# Create permissions for group to write and files created by owner are only writeable by owner

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I have created a folder, `/hello`: it has the following permissions:

```
Owner = rwx
Group = rwx
Others = r
```

and the folder is owned by `john` and belongs to the group `sales`. I have created another user named `david` and added him to the group `sales`.

Currently, the files created by `john` are:

```
Owner = rw
Group = rw
Others = r
```

and files created by `david` are:

```
Owner = rw
Group = r
Others = r
```

I do not want files created by `john` to have write permissions granted by default to the `sales` group.

I have tried changing the permissions and it resulted in `david` not being able to write into the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, concerning the read permission for Others on /hello, you probably want either no read permission at all, or you want Read and Execute permission on /hello. Execute permission on a directory means the user can do an ls in the directory.  Read without Exec permission means that the other user would be able to read any file in that directory, but only if they knew the name of the file.  It's rare that this is desired.

Second, if files are created by John are always readable by others, then, you can't stop David from reading them.

You can set the default permissions a user creates files as using the umask command.  Put this line in John and David's .bashrc (or equivalent):

```
umask 7
```

Now, when John creates files in /hello, they will be owner and group of john.

```
-rw-rw---- 1 john  john  0 Jun 28 22:05 foo
```

David will not be able to read this file.

Another possibility is, instead of using a group names sales, simply add john to David's group.  John will then be able to read/write David's files but not the other way around.

Some other interesting things you might consider.  You can set the gid flag on the /hello directory and then when files are created by either John or David, they will be in the sales group.  Hence readable and writable by both.  Not what you asked for, but this is how you do that.

Comment: You got the directory read/exec permissions kind of backwards: the directory's **read** permission governs whether or not the user can do a directory listing, and the directory's **execute** permission is a pre-requisite for accessing any files within the directory by known filename, but the file's own permission settings can still restrict access further. **Read without Exec** on a directory means a plain directory listing is *all* you can do: even `ls -l` will report file properties as question marks, as its attempts to `stat()` the files within the directory will fail.